# How to turn off or delete the default lubuntu panel in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, delete, lxpanel

I am right now experimenting with cairo dock and so far so good. I want to turn off the default lubuntu panel for which currently i dont find a need for. anyone with know how pls help me do this. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use the *Preferences - Default applications for LXSession* menu option...

[image]

Then as part of the core-applications tab - just remove the "lxpanel" text as shown.  This will stop the lxpanel application from running leaving you with Cairo.  To reverse - simply add "lxpanel" back into this text field.